# Does API access token that only have access to public information need to be kept secret?

Tags: web-application, api, access-token

I found a Instagram Basic Display API access token leaked in a website. This token belongs to a Instagram marketing account of this website. Using my leet investigating skill, below are the information i have.

- This token has 3 months valid period
- This token is in use (i see it's refreshed last week when its valid period is going to end), although i cannot find where it is used
- This token is an User Access Token for querying data from Basic Display API. Doc here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api
- This access token only has read access to public information :(
- This token will be temporarily rate limited if using too much

Do you know of any impact i can do with this access token other than rate limiting it?

Also, if this token needs to be kept secret, how can we protect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very specific to the usage of 'Instagram Basic Display API(Long live access token)' which is not just limited to display/access public information of a profile.

You can perform [Refresh Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/refresh_access_token#reading) everyday which leads to DOS attack. ([User node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user) and [Media node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview/permissions#instagram-graph-user-media) can be accessed only with latest access token). Exceeding [Rate limit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting#platform-rate-limits) also leads to DOS attack. You can control entire account if you can get [Graph API token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api) :)

Irrespective of it's usage, every API access token to be protected and how to protect is depend on your application architecture. There are many articles listing best practices. [Reference-01](https://medium.com/@benjamin.botto/secure-access-token-storage-with-single-page-applications-part-1-9536b0021321)   [Reference-02](https://dzone.com/articles/security-best-practices-for-managing-api-access-to) [Reference-03](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/token-storage)